# Fast way to get two first and last characters of a string from the input

Tags: c++, string

- I need to read a string from the input
- a string has its length from 2 letters up to 1000 letters
- I only need 2 first letters, 2 last letters, and the size of the entire string

Here is my way of doing it, HOWEVER, I do believe there is a smarter way, which is why I am asking this question. Could you please tell me, unexperienced and new C++ programmer, what are possible ways of doing this task better?

Thank you.

```
string word;
getline(cin, word);

// results - I need only those 5 numbers:
int l = word.length();
int c1 = word[0];
int c2 = word[1];
int c3 = word[l-2];
int c4 = word[l-1];
```

Why do I need this? I want to encode a huge number of really long strings, but I figured out I really need only those 5 values I mentioned, the rest is redundant. How many words will be loaded? Enough to make this part of code worth working on :)

Comment: What kind of input are you reading from? And, have you profiled this code to see exactly how much time is spent on it? I don't doubt there are faster ways to do this, but I wonder how much faster could they be and if it will make a difference.

Comment: agreed with Rodrigo, how long is this block of code taking to execute per word?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help! This is the standard input, just what will be loaded "from the console". After this part of code I start working on numbers (it's a graph, preparation for Bellman-Ford). Well, always reading from the input is too long and could be better :D

Comment: Well, even milliseconds matter here, this is an academic task.

Comment: you should use stoi(word[i]) function

Comment: It's important to eval really where the time is spent on your code. You could be surprised as where the real bottlenecks are. Are you sure the problem is with the code that encodes the words, but not the "getline" part?

Comment: @IrrationalPerson No, that would give a completely wrong result. But I admit it’s a bit unclear why the characters are declared as `int` rather than `char`.

Comment: You might look at using `grep` to do this for you. It's crazy optimized.

Comment: You could use scanf and control character %n which will store the number of characters already processed by scanf, but in that way, you have to use array of chars in scanf and then build a string, it would be interesting to compare the performance of your solution and this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take you at your word that this is something that is worth optimizing to an extreme. The method you've shown in the question is already the most straight-forward way to do it.

I'd start by using memory mapping to map chunks of the file into memory at a time. Then, loop through the buffer looking for newline characters. Take the first two characters after the previous newline and the last two characters before the one you just found. Subtract the address of the second newline from the first to get the length of the line. Rinse, lather, and repeat.

Obviously some care will need to be taken around boundaries, where one newline is in the previous mapped buffer and one is in the next.

Answer (score 1):

The first two letters are easy to obtain and fast.

The issue is with the last two letters.

In order to read a text line, the input must be scanned until it finds an end-of-line character (usually a *newline*).  Since your text lines are variable, there is no fast solution here.

You can mitigate the issue by reading in blocks of data from the file into memory and searching memory for the line endings.  This avoids a call to `getline`, and it avoids a double search for the end of line (once by `getline` and the other by your program).

If you change the input to be fixed with, this issue can be sped up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize this (although I can't imagine why you would want to do that, but surely you have your reasons), the first thing to do is to get rid of `std::string` and read the input directly. That will spare you one copy of the whole string.

If your input is `stdin`, you will be slowed down by the buffering too. As it has already been said, the best speed woukd be achieved by reading big chunks from a file in binary mode and doing the end of line detection yourself.

At any rate, you will be limited by the I/O bandwidth (disk access speed) in the end.